# iOS cURL commands only work on WiFi - iOS

Tags: ios, curl, jailbreak, cydia

I have a strange issue with `cURL` on a jailbroken iPhone (iOS 10). It works fine when I'm on WiFi but when I switch to my carrier, I get an error. For example, curl google.com produces:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.217.4.46: Network is unreachable

I was able to use `cURL` before without issue on 10.2 (recently used Cydia Eraser to start fresh). Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Check the route table. Do you have default gateway set when on mobile data.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to check this on iOS?

Comment: `netstat -nr` as usual? Probably needs to be installed from Cydia first.